How to resolve invalid argument error when initializing web driver in Selenium c#?
I downloaded the chrome web driver for scraping, I then installed the C# Nuget Selenium package and wrote the following code below to start the scraping process, I then get an exception with the message that I have used an invalid argument in the options supplied to the Web Driver constructor
 try
     {
     string chrome_path = "C:\\Users\\HP\\PycharmProjects\\Scraping\\chromedriver.exe";
     //try and use the web driver to mine for the odds from the site
     var data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
     {
         {"Home", new List<string>() },
         {"Draw", new List<string>() },
         {"Away", new List<string>() },
     };
     //define options to run the driver
     var options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.AddArgument("--headless");
     options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
     options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
     //create a new driver
     using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(chrome_path, options))
     {
         //navigate to the required URL
         driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.betexplorer.com");
         //scroll the page for the elements to become fully rendered

     }
 }catch (WebDriverArgumentException ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
     }
 }

The error invalid argument session-info: chrome-headless-shell=125.0.6422.113

where do you use the "data"

try to remove -- with arguments like options.AddArgument("headless")

@QiangFu, i read the fixture details from the site into that dictionary

As of Selenium 4.6, SeleniumManager was added and it automatically takes care of downloading and configuring the appropriate driver for you. So, you no longer need to use a DriverManager or specify the path, etc.
Your code can be simplified to
try
{
    //try and use the web driver to mine for the odds from the site
    var data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
    {
        {"Home", new List<string>() },
        {"Draw", new List<string>() },
        {"Away", new List<string>() },
    };
    //define options to run the driver
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("--headless");
    options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    //create a new driver
    using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(options))
    {
        //navigate to the required URL
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.betexplorer.com");
        //scroll the page for the elements to become fully rendered

    }
}
catch (WebDriverArgumentException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
}

